# Pattern match on enum type don't care about arguments

Tags: rust, pattern-matching

```rs
enum Foo {
  Bar(usize, usize),
  Baz(isize),
}

impl Operator {
    fn value(&self) -> usize {
        use Foo::*;
        match (self) {
            Bar(_) => 1,
            Baz(_) => 2,
        }
    }
}
```

neither `Bar(_)`, `Bar`, nor `Bar()` work.

I just want to pattern-match the enum type, and the arguments don't matter at all. I would prefer to not have to remember how many `_` I need to put for each enum variant, and not have to change these patterns in the case that the enum definition changes.

Answer (score 1):

Since `Bar` has two arguments you either have to match them both:

```rust
match self {
       Bar(_, _) => 1,
       Baz(_) => 2,
}
```

or use `..`

```rust
match self {
    Bar(..)
    Baz(_) => 2,
}
```

Comment: Looks like `(..)` might have been exactly what I'm after. Hope it doesn't have any performance cost.